# how to setup mongodb environment in php 7.2

Tags: php, mongodb, php-7, php-7.2, php-7.0

I am trying to setup MongoDB with PHP.

I am using  XAMPP and my PHP version is 7.2 I cant find any clear documentation about this can somebody help me.

I downloaded the driver for my PHP version from `pecl.php` and placed it in ext folder of PHP directory.  I have also added the `.dll` file in `php.ini` file at dynamic extensions I have added my PHP folder directory at environmental variables. I have restarted my Apache server. But somehow I cant find mongo in my `phpinfo`.

Can somebody help me.

Thankyou.

Comment: use this package https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-library

Comment: thank you for the reply praneeth. I am using a windows operating system so i cant follow the instructions mentioned in the package.Anyway thank you for your time.

Comment: You know hhow tobusee composer ?

Comment: Its works in any os

Comment: No praneeth iam not familiar with composer can you send me a link to learn how to user composer.

Comment: try this https://scotch.io/tutorials/a-beginners-guide-to-composer

Comment: Thanks for the link :)